# Constraining the Genetic Algorithm in MATLAB so that the solutions are all between 2 and 20, and are integers

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

How can I constrain the Genetic Algorithm in MATLAB so that the solutions are all between 2 and 20, and are integers?

I am using the function:

```
x = ga(@myFitnessfcn,nvars,A,b,[],[],LB,UB,nonlcon,IntCon)
```

Where myFitnessfcn takes two inputs and returns a scalar output.

However myFitnessfcn can only take integer inputs that are between 2 and 20.

How would I implement this?

My best attempt so far is:

```
A = [1, 1; -1, -1]
b = [20; -2]
IntCon = [1, 2]
LB = 2
UB = 20
nonlcon = []
```

But this just tried to evaluate `myFitnessfcn` with `[4, 1872]`

[Here is the MATLAB page on ga](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/gads/ga.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see `InitialPopulation` and `PopInitRange` in options of `gaoptimset`.
you can initialize a sequence of integers in the range 2 to 20 as your initial population.

then you might use IntCon.

OR

as a first statement in your `myFitnessfcn`

```
model=round(model);
if model > 20 || model < 2
   fitness=1e20;
else
   % evaluate the original fitness function
end
```

this way model parameters fed to your fitness function are always integers. and since any model with values less than 2 or more than 20 will be assigned really bad value of fitness (1e20 for example), this is essentially what Simon said, such models will be automatically removed from the population after 2-3 generations.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I don't know Matlab, but in general in a GA, you can set a low or 0 fitness when the solution is outside that range, and some higher number when it is within the range.

Comment: The problem is that when the ga tries to evaluate myFitnessfcn with a number that is non integer or outside of the range, it returns an error and stops.

Comment: Again, I don't know matlab, but I would put a bounds check at the start of the fitness function that returns 0 or minus infinity or similar if out of bounds, else evaluate the rest of the fitness function. So you just need to check for the bad inputs, and return the lowest possible fitness score in those cases, else continue to evaluate fitness.